# Intercept browser requests for resources

Tags: javascript

Is there any way in which one could load an initial script (a file at the top of the page) that then attempts to intercept all other requests for resources (scripts, css, images, etc.) as the page continues to load?

The purpose of this interception is to instead serve the files from cache (localStorage, indexedDB, other) or even from a remote peer via webrtc in an agnostic manner that does not depend on how the application/page is put together.

I'm aware of cache manifest/offline approaches but the point here is to grab the requested resource and proxy it from a location of choice.

Comment: @Bergi It looks like I updated/edited my question a second to late concerning appcache manifests. :)

Comment: Yeah, you did :-) But no, there's no builtin way to intercept all HTTP requests, the only way is not to start them at all (in the normal way) but route resource creations through your custom resolver (i.e. write `<script>resolver.load("img", "…")</script>` instead of `<img …>`)

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. You see I'm attempting to write a framework that will serve resources from peer hosts via webrtc. While I can do what I'm looking to do by rewriting the markup of DOM elements href/src attributes (on the server), making requests to point to an internal JS callback/proxy client side, but I'm stumped how I would do something like this for applications that are using requirejs or similar OR in any case where resources are added/loaded dynamically/programatically.

Comment: Basically I need to know how to accesss a client's browser cache for serving to another connecting client without the connecting client downloading resources from the central server (if there are other peers on the network available with the resources).

Comment: If the app is using requirejs or similar and loads its ressources programatically anyway, then it should be easy to intercept those calls (by overwriting require's loader), opposed to statically declared ressources that are fetched by the browser without any possibility to interfer. And no, you cannot programmatically access the HTTP cache of a browser from page JS.

Comment: Would anyone care to explore an alternative approximation for a method to accomplish nearly the same task?

Answer (score 8):

A solution would be to register a service worker to intercept requests inside the very first script.

The only **problem** is that this **registration is asynchronous** while resources are loaded synchronously, which means that on first load the original resources will be fetched.

Once the service worker is loaded though, a simple **page refresh can load the intercepted resources**.

The code below detects whether the service worker is loaded for the first time (or after `Ctrl+F5`), and if yes, it performs a page refresh in the registration callback. Its a **solution to above issue**, probably not the most elegant.

In the example below the image/js resources are loaded from external urls, but it could be any source. `script.js` could be added on top of all the pages.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/dP6wr0hB1gbXDeQs?preview

html

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h2>My intercepted page</h2>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

    <script src="jquery.js"></script>

    <div class="placeholder">a</div>
    <img src="z9t29Bk.gif">
    <img src="y2kChjZ.gif">
    <script>$(".placeholder").text("loaded jquery version:"+$.fn.jquery)</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) { 
    var interceptorLoaded = navigator.serviceWorker.controller!=null;
    window.addEventListener('load', function() { 
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js')
      .then(function(registration){
          console.log('ServiceWorker registration successful with scope: ', registration.scope);
          if(!interceptorLoaded){
            //refresh after interceptor was loaded but only if the interceptor was not already loaded.
            window.location=window.location.href; 
          }
      },
        function(err) { // registration failed :( 
        console.log('ServiceWorker registration failed: ', err); 
      }); 
  }); 
}
```

sw.js

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log("REQUEST:", event.request.url);
  var url = event.request.url;
  if (url.endsWith("/jquery.js")) {
    event.respondWith(
      fetch('https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js')
    );
  }else if(url.endsWith(".jpg") || url.endsWith(".png") || url.endsWith(".gif")){ 
      event.respondWith(fetch("https://i.imgur.com/"+url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1),{
        mode: 'cors',
    }));
  }
})
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerContainer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can use [PerformanceObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-CN/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver/PerformanceObserver).

```js
const observer2 = new PerformanceObserver((entries) => {
  entries.getEntriesByType("resource").forEach(res => console.log(res.toJSON()))
});
observer2.observe({ entryTypes: ["resource"] });

// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/my_arrow_top.9283728e.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3266.3399999946705, duration: 26.8900000010035, initiatorType: "img", …}
// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/my_icon.f210d94a.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3266.9349999996484, duration: 44.04000000067754, initiatorType: "img", …}
// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/my_list_bill.90ea3a37.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3267.26499999495, duration: 46.875, initiatorType: "img", …}
// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/list_arrow.46347d10.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3268.0749999999534, duration: 49.924999999348074, initiatorType: "img", …}
// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/my_list_card.fa9a853c.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3269.0549999970244, duration: 53.15500000142492, initiatorType: "img", …}
// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/my_list_invite.89c26861.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3270.7399999999325, duration: 56.94499999663094, initiatorType: "img", …}
// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/my_list_loan.ebbd740a.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3271.2849999952596, duration: 60.380000002624, initiatorType: "img", …}
// {name: "http://localhost:8080/1.1.0/img/my_list_about.cacfe7f5.svg", entryType: "resource", startTime: 3271.7199999970035, duration: 61.67000000277767, initiatorType: "img", …
```

Comment: Downvoted for not answering the question: "The purpose of this interception is to instead serve the files from cache". I don't believe that `PerformanceObserver` can manipulate the response.

Comment: Sorry, the conclusion is too arbitrary, this obviously can only be loaded as a record resource. If you want to intercept resources, maybe `service worker` can do it,  look [msw](https://github.com/mswjs/msw)